# Передача объектов POST-методу

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String home7(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttrubute("user", new User());
    model.addAttrubute("test", new Test());
    return "test";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String home71(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, @ModelAttribute("test") Test test) {        
    return "welcome";
}
```

При передаче POST-запросом `user` и `test` почему-то обнуляются. Вероятно, я их просто не передаю в форме.(так как не умею) А может, подход неправильный. Так вот, каким образом можно передать объекты `user` и `test` post запросом?

Помогите пожалуйста или тыкнете хотя бы в правильную сторону поиска решения. Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что `@ModelAttribute` может быть только один.

Давайте предположим, что их может быть два. В форме есть поле `name`, классы `User` и `Test` тоже содержат такое поле. Вопрос: к какому из классов относится поле в форме? Наиболее вероятно, что дабы избежать такой путаницы Spring поддерживает ровно один объект с аннотацией `@ModelAttribute`.

Предлагаю создать еще один класс, который бы объединял в себе `User` и `Test`. Тогда должно работать.

Comment: спасибо за ответ огромное. моя проблема скорее была в том, что я не понимал глупости своих задумок и в ограниченности знаний. спасибо вам огромное за ответ